# Is it professional to bring sample reports to a reporting job interview

Tags: report

I have a job interview late next week as a report developer.  At this point it sounds much more interesting than what I am doing now (customer support) and pays better as well.  I have some of the software that they use, and I was wondering if it looks professional if I make some reports off of some sample data and bring it with me to the interview. Or will it come off looking desperate?

Comment: Print one of the reports on gold leaf paper and, at the end of the interview, delicately pull it out by the corners and hand it to them as if it's your crowning achievement. Have an awestruck impression on your face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Print them out and put them in your notebook. If they ask if you have samples of your work, BOOM, there you go. If they don't ask, don't show them and you never have to worry about looking desperate.

Answer (score 1):

Bring them and at the right time offer them but don't push them.  If they are interested they will take them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the sample data is not proprietary to your current employer, otherwise your attempt to impress them may backfire badly.  You don't want them to think that you might be just as free with their data.